# How can I add a div to a div on a button click in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a button on the click of which I want to keep adding divs as children to a parent div.I want to do this in angularJS.Could some1 please give me an example of how to achieve this?I don't know if this matters but the dynamic child div I am trying to add has an ng-include in it. 
`<button ng-click="callme()">
        add dynamic divs
    </button>
    <div class="parentDiv">
    </div>`

The dynamic div that I want to add to the parentDiv on click is as follows:
    `<div ng-include="/xyz.html"></div>`

Comment: Not very sophisticated but you could use `ng-show`/`hide` and not try to add in components

Answer (score 1):

ng-show or ng-if I guess will not work for you hwre since you wnat the user to be able to add as many child divs as clicks they make right? If that is the case, I would use directives to accomplish this task:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lfrecia/cgt0k08q/)

```
 //Directive for adding divs
    myApp.directive("adddivs", function($compile){
        return function(scope, element){
            element.bind("click", function(){
                angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).append($compile("<div ng-include='/xyz.html'></div>")(scope));
            });
        };
    });

    //Directive that returns an element which adds divs
    myApp.directive("adddiv", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<button adddivs>Click to add div</button>"
        }
    });
```

And in your partial:

```
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <adddiv></adddiv>
    <div id="space-for-buttons"></section>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: thank you marabunta...I somehow have a bug. The button is not getting displayed. I tried doing exactly how you did. Any guess on what could be the problem?

Comment: the button is not displayed at all and neither do I get any console errors

Comment: check your  directive "adddiv" and <adddiv></adddiv> in the template have the same name?

Comment: my naming here was not very good, check that you did not mistype, you can see here that there are adddiv and adddivs in directives and tags, check naming

Comment: What if I want to let the add button be where it is and create a directive to append the child div to parent?<button adddivs>add child</button>... Can you let me know how can i do that?

Comment: I will try doing it that way

Comment: just add the <button adddivs>button</button> button, take out adddiv directive

Comment: Thank you bro... I will keep trying.